# Unable to Use CanvasRenderingContext2D Methods with Variable Assignment

Tags: javascript, canvas, callback, html5-canvas, closures

I am working on a webapp that uses the canvas to draw a lot of stroked and/or filled rectangles using the HTML/JavaScript Canvas API.  Since I have to use the exact same coordinates for both stroked and filled rectangles, I want to assign the current drawing function (either `ctx.strokeRect` or `ctx.fillRect`) to a variable and call it later.

Unfortunately, trying to use a variable holding a CanvasRenderingContext2D function throws an error: `'fillRect' called on an object that does not implement interface CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, which throws an error drawing the second rectangle:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// draw the top rectangle - works fine
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
// draw the bottom rectangle - crashes with an error
(f => f(0, 50, 100, 50))(ctx.fillRect);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

An error is also thrown if the method is assigned to a variable, such as:

```
const fn = ctx.fillRect;
fn(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

Why can't canvas context functions can't be used this way?  Or can they be used this way, and am I missing a mistake in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these methods are inherited from the CanvasRenderingContext2D prototype, and are the same exact function for all instances of such a context.

```js
const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
const fn1 = ctx1.fillRect;
const fn2 = ctx2.fillRect;

console.log( "fn1 === fn2:", fn1 === fn2 );
console.log( "fn1 === proto.fillRect:", fn1 === CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillRect );
```

What you want is to create a copy of this function that is *[bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)* to your particular instance of a context:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// draw the top rectangle - works fine
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
(f => f(0, 50, 100, 50))(ctx.fillRect.bind(ctx));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```